# conditional distribution of the average given the difference

Tags: probability, statistics

$X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are iid from uniform distribution [$\theta -1/2$, $\theta +1/2$]. Suppose we know the value of the variable $Z = max(X_{1},X_{2}) - min(X_{1},X_{2}) = z (z >0) $. What is the conditional probability distribution of  $\bar{X_{n}} =X_{1}+X_{2}$ given that $Z = z$ ?

Probability and Statistics (4th edition) Morris H.DeGroot page 493 claims that $\bar{X_{n}}$ given $Z = z$ is uniform on the interval [$\theta -1/2(1-z)$, $\theta +1/2(1-z)$]. But I don't think this is the case.

Let's say $Y_{2} =  max(X_{1},X_{2})$. Then $\bar{X_{n}} =Y_{2}-z/2$. Since $Y_{2}$ is the maximum from a sample of size two of uniform distribution, the CDF of $Y_{2}$ is $[F(y)]^2$ , F(y) is the CDF of uniform distribution [$\theta -1/2$, $\theta +1/2$].

As we can see $\bar{X_{n}}$ is just a constant off $Y_{2}$ and $Y_{2}$ is not uniformly distributed, therefore I don't think $\bar{X_{n}}$ is uniformly distributed.

Comment: And... what do you think instead?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you consider two cases: $X_1 \leq X_2$ and $X_2 \leq X_1$. Suppose for instance that $X_1 \leq X_2$ and let $F$ be the conditional probability distribution function of $\overline{X}_n$ given $Z = z$. Then
\begin{align}
F(t) &= \mathbb{P}(X_1+X_2 \leq t \ | \ X_2 - X_1 =z) \\
&=\mathbb{P}(X_1+X_2 \leq t \ | \ X_2 = X_1+z) \\
&=\mathbb{P}(2X_1+z \leq t \ | \ X_2 = X_1+z) \\
\end{align}
To proceed use the fact that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent r.v.